# Unterminated String error moving JSON object from server to client (VB.NET)

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, jsonschema

I'm attempting to use NewtonSoft.JSON for .NET to serialize an object so I can pass that data to the client, I have the following classes that store the data on the server side:

```
Public Class BankAccountPaymentProfile
    Public Property BankAccountProfileID As String
    Public Property AccountNumber As String
    Public Property AccountType As String
    Public Property RoutingNumber As String
    Public Property BankName As String
    Public Property NameOnAccount As String
    Public Property BillTo As New BillToProfile
End Class

Public Class BillToProfile
    Public Property billTofirstName As String = ""
    Public Property billTolastName As String = ""
    Public Property BillToaddress As String = ""
    Public Property billTocity As String = ""
    Public Property billTostate As String = ""
    Public Property billTozip As String = ""
    Public Property billTophoneNumber As String = ""
    Public Property billToemail As String = ""
End Class
```

In the code behind I instanciate the classes and populate the data and then serialize it with this line of code:

```
Profiles = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BankAccountProfile, Formatting.Indented)
```

On the client side I have this jQuery Function which I call in (document).ready to get the data to the client side:

```
    function GetProfileList() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: '{object:[<%=Profiles%>]}',
            url: "Subscription.aspx/MyProfiles",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Failed");
                debugger;
            }
        });
    };
```

I get an error "Unterminated String" in the client browser, the data showing on the client side in the debugger is:

```
'{object:[{
  "BankAccountProfileID": "1503460396",
  "AccountNumber": "XXXX7620",
  "AccountType": "0",
  "RoutingNumber": "XXXX0010",
  "BankName": "Bank Of AHoles",
  "NameOnAccount": "Firstname Lastname",
  "BillTo": {
    "billTofirstName": "",
    "billTolastName": "",
    "BillToaddress": "",
    "billTocity": "",
    "billTostate": "",
    "billTozip": "",
    "billTophoneNumber": "",
    "billToemail": ""
  }
}]}'
```

I thought maybe it was because I had an object nested in a object so I removed the `BillTo` object, same error.  The data is obviously getting to the client, but for the error, I see nothing wrong with the string.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I over complicated things, all I needed to do was get the serialized string back to the client, an ajax call was unnecessary.

In (document).ready:

```
// Creates an object of profiles contained in the JSON string
var = var Profiles = $(<%=Profiles%>);
var = accountprofileid = Profiles.accountprofileid;
```

... etc ...

Done ....